# Checkbox & Check all function in Datatable Jquery PHP Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

The below is the php script for fetchingd data from database table in json to Datatable;

```html
<?php
/* Database connection start */
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password1";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

/* Database connection end */


// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;


$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
 0 =>'employee_name', 
 1 => 'employee_salary',
 2=> 'employee_age'
);

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age ";
$sql.=" FROM employee";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.


$sql = "SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age ";
$sql.=" FROM employee WHERE 1=1";
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
 $sql.=" AND ( employee_name LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
 $sql.=" OR employee_salary LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";

 $sql.=" OR employee_age LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
}
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
/* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */ 
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");

$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
 $nestedData=array(); 

 $nestedData[] = $row["employee_name"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["employee_salary"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["employee_age"];
 
 $data[] = $nestedData;
}



$json_data = array(
   "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
   "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
   "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
   "data"            => $data   // total data array
   );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```

And below is my datatable page;

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": true,
     "ajax":{
      url :"employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource
      type: "post",  // method  , by default get
      error: function(){  // error handling
       $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
       $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
       $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");
       
      }
     }
    } );
   } );
  </script>
```

I m trying to add checkbox in first column to select one row or multiple or all row and submit.

But I am not able to do so, can anyone help me out to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](http://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plugin of jQuery DataTables.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'columnDefs': [
      {
         'targets': 0,
         'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
         }
      }
   ],
   'select': {
      'style': 'multi'
   },
   'order': [[1, 'asc']]
});
```